# Привязка DataGridViewTextBoxColumn к другой таблице

Tags: c#

Привет всем. Такой вопрос.
У DataGridView есть типа колонок. К примеру, есть такой тип колонки, как DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. У этой колонки, есть привязка к источнику данных Binding Source. То что мне и надо. Но, мне не нужен ComboBox. Мне бы желательно TextBox.

Короче говоря, мне нужен DataGridViewTextBoxColumn с такими же свойствами привязки к источнику данных как и DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.

Не подскажете как такое реализовать?

Comment: Колонка типа ComboBox имеет встроенный список строк, который привязывается к дополнительному  источнику данных через Binding Source. Колонка типа ТехtBox не имеет имеет дополнительных данных и ее содержимое автоматически связано с текущей записью. То есть Вы хотите невозможного. Уточните Вашу задачу.

Comment: Что значит невозможного? Нет ничего невозможного! Покрайнее мере на C++ точно. Но мне нужно написать на C#. Этот язык ограничен чем-то чтоли?

Comment: "...Нет ничего невозможного! Покрайнее мере на C++ ..." - с этим не возможно не согласиться, однако прежде, чем что-то ваять нужна постановка задачи. Я предполагаю (не будучи Святым духом), что Вы желаете, чтобы ячейка грида разворачивалась в список. DataGridViewTextBox этого не может. Для этого используются другие средства.

Comment: Нет, я не хочу чтобы ячейка разворачивалась в список. Для этого есть DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, и у него как раз есть свойства привязки к таблице! Но мне нужно такие же свойства привязки как и у DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, но вид должен быть как у DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, так как на одну ячейку 1 строка из таблицы

Comment: Грубо говоря, если бы я делал это на C++, то я бы наследовал новый класс от DataGridViewTextBoxColumn и добавил свойства привязки к источнику данных, как у DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. Но из-за узких знаний в C# обращаюсь сюда:)

Comment: Вы так не описали, что Ваш специализированный класс должен делать, поэтому возможны только общие советы: 1. Использовать готовый DataGrid сторонних производителей (Например DevExpress); 2. Создать свой класс, имеющий интерфейсы для встраивания в Grid. Это дело хлопотное, но ваяется он точно также, как и в с++.  Разницы в методе никакой нет.

Comment: Я уже несколько раз описал, что мой класс должен делать. Он должен иметь привязку к источнику данных -BindingSource. У класса DataGridViewComboBoxColumn есть такая возможность за счет свойств, таких как DataSource, DataPropertyName, DisplayMember и ValueMember. Так вот у DataGridViewTextBoxColumn таких свойств нет. Следовательно мне нужно как то их реализовать. В голову пришло только создать класс наследник от DataGridViewTextBoxColumn и реализовать эти свойства для привязки к источнику данных. Но из-за слабых знаний C# я не знаю как их описать. Поэтому обращаюсь к Вам

Comment: Вот, то что Вы сейчас написали, нужно было добавить в текст вопроса. Я взял на себя смелость, это сделать.

Comment: Я думаю, что сейчас после коррекции последуют новые просьбы об уточнении Вашего вопросы. Вас будут спрашивать, как будут использоваться привязанные данные. Дело в том, что как правило, содержания отображаемого в ячейки проще приготовить, манипулируя с источником данных.

Comment: Мою правку отменили с обоснованием "...Правка не соответствует исходному содержанию сообщения..." - поэтому, если Вы хотите, чтобы люди заинтересовались Вашим вопросом, Вам придется его править самому.

Comment: Вы пользовались когда-нибудь столбцами в DataGridView с типом DataGridViewComboBoxColumn? Видели там привязку к источнику данных через свойства DataSource, DataPropertyName, DisplayMember и ValueMember? Вот нужно реализовать тоже самое, только для столбцов с типом DataGridViewTextBoxColumn